# SQL CE 3.5 on WindowsMobile .NET application deployment

Tags: .net, database, windows-mobile, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

Is there a way of automatic depoloyment of SQL CE 3.5 dlls without necessity of installing separate CABs on Windows Mobile?
I have a .NET CF 3.5 application that uses SqlCe assembly and makes use of Sql CE 3.5 in-proc datavase. Currently when I want to install this application and have it working with sdf database, I have to install 3 CABs from Microsoft too. Those CABs are installers for SQL CE 3.5. Can I avoid this step?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Just include the SQL Compact assemblies (native and managed) in your application CAB.

Comment: How? I have only CAB installers for SQL CE 3.5?

Comment: No, all of the binaries are in the distribution too.  For WinMo the native pieces are at %PROGRAM_FILES%\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Devices\wce400\armv4 and the managed piece is at %PROGRAM_FILES%\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Devices